# In Google.Apis.Pagespeedonline.v5 how to get all categories in one call?

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using `Google.Apis.Pagespeedonline.v5` (nuget) to perform the analysis on my site.

By performing the analysis directly from the API Explorer site you can perform the test on all five categories.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed

However, using the dotnet api, the category parameter only accepts one CategoryEnum, so, I can only get the result in one category per request.

I wonder if it is possible to get all categories in a single request

```
var initializer = new Initializer()
{
     ApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     BaseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed",
     GZipEnabled = true
};

var service = new PagespeedonlineService(initializer);

var request = new RunpagespeedRequest(service, "https://www.google.com");

request.Category = CategoryEnum.Accessibility;
request.Locale = "pt";
request.Strategy = StrategyEnum.Desktop;

var response = request.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it this way:

```
GET https://pagespeedonline.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?category=ACCESSIBILITY&category=PERFORMANCE&locale=pt&strategy=DESKTOP&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&prettyPrint=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1
```

But in your situation maybe you can change base URL to look like:

```
BaseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?category=ACCESSIBILITY&category=PERFORMANCE"
```

Give it a try this way